# No boot device found. Press any key to continue

Tags: ssd

I took out the hard drive from my Dell Latitude E5420 notebook, put in an ADATA S599 solid state drive, and installed Ubuntu 11.10.

When I boot, the Dell BIOS splash screen appears with a progress bar, which quickly fills up, and the screen goes black. All of this is like it was before. At this point, the OS splash screen should fade in. Instead, I was dismayed to see simply the following, in white text on a black screen:

```
No boot device found. Press any key to continue
```

After looking around for the Any key (just kidding) I press a key, and the Dell BIOS splash screen appears again with a progress bar, which quickly fills up, and the screen goes black. This time, however, the Ubuntu splash screen shows up, Ubuntu opens up, and all is normal.

Every time I shut down, however, this happens again. It's like a game the computer and I play together. The computer has **never** started up without first saying:

```
No boot device found. Press any key to continue
```

and it has **always** started up after I press any key to continue.

It also starts up fine if I click **Restart** instead of **Shut Down**. Thoughts?

Comment: Close enough, AHCI :)

Comment: Did you check you default boot drive in the BIOS?  Since removing the default hard drive the default boot drive setting would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Change between the RAID and AHCI mode in the BIOS.

Comment: Thank you, that worked but caused my DVD drive to disappear. In my BIOS, SATA Operations has three choices: Disabled, ATA, and AHCI. AHCI was chosen. I changed it to ATA, and the boot errors disappeared. But now when I pop in a CD or DVD the OS never mounts them. The DVD-ROM drive doesn't even appear in the /dev directory anymore (it used to be /dev/sr0)

Comment: @AndrewBanks: Hmm, tricky. I'm not good enough in Linux to knaw that...

Comment: @AndrewBanks boot another OS (LiveCD or something) and check if it sees your drive. Also, do you have latest BIOS version?